# Why there is a difference in the text size when show it in one Text ui and another Text ui with the same settings?

Tags: unity-game-engine

The post is a bit long but I tried to explain everything that is connected to the issue.

This screenshot is of the parent ui texts canvas.

[image: Parent main canvas of the ui texts settings]

[image: Description text ui Image settings]

This is a screenshot of the description ui text the text in the game looks very big the fonts are very big and stretched.

[image: Description ui text settings]

This is a screenshot of the scene text Image settings :

[image: Scene image settings]

And the scene ui text settings :

[image: scene ui text settings]

This is a screenshot of the scene ui text when running the game from the exe build file :

[image: Scene ui text in game]

And last the description ui text in game when running the build exe file :

[image: Description ui text in game]

How can I make some ui text that will be display the text the same in all the cases something that will be readable nice not too small and not too big ?

In the scene text the text is smaller because I wanted the text to be a bit under the player mouth. In the description text is a bit bigger but then everything get messed.

I think I want the text to be shown like in the scene ui text in all the places. I think the size is fine. but not sure how to do it.

Comment: I would try adding the "Default UI Material" to the "Scene Image" object. If that doesn't work, try duplicating the "Description Image" object with the child and do your edits on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of things here that should get your text working nicely across the board.

1. Firstly, at your root Canvas object, you'll usually have a Canvas Scaler there. The default of "Constant Pixel Size" is often exactly what you don't want. I normally have it set to "Scale With Screen Size", and then set the resolution to 1920x1080. I do that because 1920x1080 (16:9) is the standard Full HD screen size, so you can bet that most of your screen layout is going to look the same across most displays.
2. The second suggestion would be to use TextMeshPro. If you haven't already got it installed through your Package Manager, then you can find it there. Here's the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/com.unity.textmeshpro.html) for that. It's FAR superior to the standard Text element and you'll notice less issues trying to get your text looking correct. It's usually just a matter of adding the TMPro_Text UI component to the same object your Text component was originally on (removing the original Text component of course).
3. I would also leave all scaling for all of your UI items set to (1, 1, 1) where you can and let and scaling be done by the Canvas Scaler. The text elements can certainly be left at (1, 1, 1) and just change the font size.

Once you get these three things sorted, your text should be the same across all of your pages, and devices.

Comment: How do I set the Image background to be automatic cover or be behind as background over all the text ? I'm using now for the scene text with text mesh pro.  scaling is set to 1,1,1 the fonts size is set to 54 Alignment is set to center and middle.  Wrapping is disabled Overflow is set to overflow and the text is shown fine for the scene but the image is too small. Is there a way to automatic fit the image to the text ? I can play with the Image width and height and the scaling but it will take time.

Comment: @DanielLip use the image RectTransform Anchor Presets box ( top left ) to define the anchors for the image. And then use the values to the right (generally 0) to stretch the image out across the anchors. https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/class-RectTransform.html

Comment: @DanielLip you probably also want Wrapping Enable. That will allow the text to wrap at the end of each line.

Answer (score 1):

This due to Scaling **Rect Transform** Component 
to solve this don't scale up or scale down UI Elements {Image ,Text, ... just keep Scale 1,1,1 } 
First I recommend You to see This to understand this Component 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FeheZqu85WI&t=6s

**Now to Solve your problem**

1. Set Scale of Description Image (1,1,1)
2. Set Scale of Description Text (1,1,1)
3. Do 1,2 with Scene Image, Scene Text
4. Change ***Width*** , ***Height*** of{Description Text, Scene Text} with small values 900*400